# Как в gradle скрипте Java проекта настроить создание константы, имеющей разные значения для разных ОС

Tags: java, linux, debian, servlet, gradle

Пишу сервлет на винде, собираю проект через `Gradle`. Запускать надо будет на `Debian`. В проекте используется путь до определённого файла в ОС (драйвер `Chrome` для `Selenium`). На винде и `Debian` он разный. Как я могу настроить варианты сборки для разных ОС так, чтобы в них была в `Java` коде доступна константа, заданная в скрипте сборки и имеющая разные значения для вариантов сборки?

В андроид это сделать легко, а вот тут сходу не сообразить. Рассмотрю вариант однозначного программного определения ОС, на коей идёт исполнение и подставление пути до файла в рантайме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Рассмотрю вариант однозначного программного определения ОС, на коей идёт исполнение и подставление пути до файла в рантайме.

Насколько я понимаю для Ваших целей достаточного грубого определения ОС: Windows и не-Windows. Тогда подойдет такой метод:

```
boolean isWindows() {
    return System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows");
}
```

Метод можно использовать при инициализации пути, например:

```
//константы
private static final String WINDOWS_PATH = "C:\\driver\\chrome.exe";
private static final String UNIX_PATH = "/usr/bin/chromedriver";    
...
//использование
pathToExecutable = isWindows() ? WINDOWS_PATH : UNIX_PATH;
```

С помощью Gradle можно записывать путь, например, [в файл properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945685/read-write-properties-file-in-gradle-build-script), после чего код будет считывать его в рантайме.

Comment: Да, такое подойдёт, спасибо) Может знаете на счёт `gradle` - в андроиде можно задавать варианты сборки `apk` файла - много чего можно намутить через это и на выходе получить очень разные `apk` файлы нажатием пары кнопок. Делается это через `buildType` и `flavors`. Можно ли вне андроида такое как-то сделать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Рад что подходит, пожалуйста! В `gradle` такое можно сделать, просто я с ним практически не работал, а экспериментировать сейчас негде. Если найду вариант опубликую здесь, а может кто-нибудь другой опытом поделится. P.S. По-моему, для настройки одного пути создавать разные сборки это перебор. Другое дело если бы в сборки входили специфичные для каждой платформы библиотеки.

Comment: В любом случае спасибо) На счёт сборок это я на будущее - ещё не изучал полностью вопрос, но, возможно, тот же драйвер для хрома можно прямо в `war` встроить и тогда уже нужны будут разные файлы для разных ОС - вот и пригодились бы варианты сборки)

Answer (score 3):

Если в самом скрипте `Gradle` то можно воспользоваться следующей конструкцией:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) {
    Тут код
}
if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_UNIX) {
    И тут код
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что это способ определения ОС на коей gradle скрипт исполняется. Если это так, то мне нужно другое - создать два варианта `war` файла. В одном у константы будет значение типа `C://driver/chrome.exe`, а в другом у этой же константы значение будет `/usr/bin/chromedriver`